# TZ parameter not working in SOLR timeseries streaming expression

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are using Solr 9.1. We want to calculate a monthly time series metric. We are using following request

```
https://localhost/solr/metrics/stream?expr=timeseries(
                metrics, 
                q="type_i:4",
                field="ended_at_dt",
                start="NOW/MONTH",
                end="NOW/MONTH+5MONTH",
                gap="+1MONTH"
            )&TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

Irrespective of TZ parameter we are getting monthly results based on UTC tie zone shown in below screnshot

[image]

While in [SOLR documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/date-formatting-math.html) It is mentioned

> By default, all date math expressions are evaluated relative to the UTC TimeZone, but the TZ parameter can be specified to override this behaviour, by forcing all date based addition and rounding to be relative to the specified time zone.
> For example, the following request will use range faceting to facet over the current month, "per day" relative UTC:

I have tested below example given in document

```
http://localhost/solr/metrics/select?q=*:*&facet.range=ended_at_dt&facet=true&facet.range.start=NOW/MONTH&facet.range.end=NOW/MONTH+5MONTH&facet.range.gap=+1MONTH&TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

And it is giving result as expected as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Please guide how to use timeseries expression to show results based on timezone.